# string break for java

Tags: java, string

I am coding in java and  I have string like this **[A⋈ (B⋈C)]⋈[D⋈ (E⋈F)]** I want to split it in a way that I get (B⋈C) in different sub string and (E⋈F) in different string.How can I do that?

I try to do it by regex and string split but it do not work for me.

```
String[] items = str.split(Pattern.quote("(?=-)"));
ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String item : items) 
{
   itemList.add(item);
}
System.out.println(itemList);
```

Comment: You only want to capture those 2 values? including the braces?

Comment: Try this regex "\(.{3}\)"

Answer (score 1):

You can this Regex: `"\\([A-Za-z⋈]*\\)"`

```
String mData = "[A⋈ (B⋈C)]⋈[D⋈ (E⋈F)] ";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\([A-Za-z⋈]*\\)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(mData);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(mData.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
}
```

Comment: Good Answer Sir!

Comment: Thanks sir :) @AbdoCosmos

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work : Try this regex "(.{3})"

Comment: that I didnt try, all I did was to create a regex. If you can pls check then let me know. :)

Comment: @Adya - This will work if you use it with Pattern and Matcher and not with `split`.

Comment: @nadra - You've not mentioned the exact output. In the future, please add *expected output* explicitly so that people will be able to give you correct answers

Comment: Thanks @TheLostMind

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the regex ("\\((.*?)\\)") works for me.